# struct pointers to same memory address producing different data?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, heap-memory

I have this simple code to read the lines of a file and store them in a struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    

struct filedata {
    char **items;
    int lines;
};    

struct filedata *read_file(char *filename) {
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");    

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't read %s \n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }    

    char rbuff;     

    int nlines = 0; // amount of lines
    int chr = 0; // character count
    int maxlen = 0; // max line length (to create optimal buffer)
    int minlen = 2; // min line length (ignores empty lines with just \n, etc)    

    while ((rbuff = fgetc(file) - 0) != EOF) {
        if (rbuff == '\n') {
            if (chr > maxlen) {
                maxlen = chr + 1;
            }    

            if (chr > minlen) {
                nlines++;
            }    

            chr = 0;
        }    

        else {
            chr++;
        }
    }    

    struct filedata *rdata = malloc(sizeof(struct filedata));
    rdata->lines = nlines;    

    printf("lines: %d\nmax string len: %d\n\n", nlines, maxlen);
    rewind(file);    

    char *list[nlines];    

    int buffsize = maxlen * sizeof(char);
    char buff[buffsize];    

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buff, buffsize, file)) {
        if (strlen(buff) > minlen) {
            list[i] = malloc(strlen(buff) * sizeof(char) + 1);
            strcpy(list[i], buff);
            i++;
        }
    }    

    rdata->items = (char **)list;
    fclose(file);    

    int c = 0;
    for (c; c < rdata->lines; c++) {
        printf("line %d: %s\n", c + 1, rdata->items[c]);
    }    

    printf("\n");
    return rdata;
}    

int main(void) {
    char fname[] = "test.txt";
    struct filedata *ptr = read_file(fname);    

    int c = 0;
    for (c; c < ptr->lines; c++) {
        printf("line %d: %s\n", c + 1, ptr->items[c]);
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output when I run it:

```
lines: 2
max string len: 6

line 1: hello
line 2: world

line 1: hello
line 2: H��
```

For some reason when it reaches the second index in ptr->items, it prints gibberish output. But yet, if I throw some printf()'s in there to show the pointer addresses, they're exactly the same.

Valgrind also prints this when iterating over the char array the second time:

```
==3777== Invalid read of size 8
==3777==    at 0x400AB3: main (test.c:81)
==3777==  Address 0xfff000540 is on thread 1's stack
==3777==  240 bytes below stack pointer
```

But that really doesn't give me any clues in this case.

I'm using gcc 4.9.4 with glibc-2.24 if that matters.

Comment: `(rbuff = fgetc(file) - 0) != EOF` compareing `char` with `EOF` doesn't seem good idea because it makes it impossible to distinguish valid character (byte) with `EOF`. Why not use `int` for `rbuff`?

Comment: `list` in `rdata->items = (char **)list;` is a local array, which may not be used after the function returns. Also, remove the cast, it doesn't help you.

Comment: @MikeCAT I didn't know `int` could contain a character too, but it seems to work. Do you know a link to a good resource that explains this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is an non-static local variable and using it after exiting its scope (returning from `read_file` in this case) will invoke *undefined behavior* because it will vanish on exiting its scope. Allocate it dynamically (typically on the heap) like

```
char **list = malloc(sizeof(char*) * nlines);
```

Adding code to check if `malloc()`s are successful will make your code better.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense. I must have went over the code 20 times but missed that sneaky part. It was really confusing since it printed "hello" fine in the second part, so I ended up thinking perhaps it was the compiler or the libc, lol :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `list` is local to `read_file`, but you store a pointer to `list` in `rdata->items`.  When `read_file` returns, `rdata->items` is a dangling pointer, and accessing it is undefined behavior.